# How to access text box from dynamic created button event

Tags: c#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {   Button lnk1 = new Button();
            lnk1.ID = "ln" + i;
             lnk1.Click += new EventHandler(lnk1_Click);
        }
        addButtons(ticketID);
    }
void lnk1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {
        ViewState["btnId"] = (sender as Button).ID;
        string queryNo=(sender as Button).Text;
        addButtons(qNo);     

    }
 void addButtons(string buttonText)
    {
        if (ViewState["btnId"] == null)
            return;
       for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)        
             {
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();

            txt.Visible = false;
            txt.ID = "TXT" + i;

            // now reply/block/unblock to particular advisor
            Button reply = new Button();
            Button block = new Button();
            reply.Width = 80;
            block.Width = 80;
            reply.ID = "RE" + i;
            reply.Click += new EventHandler(reply_Click);
            block.Click += new EventHandler(block_Click);
        }


    }
    void reply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {
        ViewState["btnId"] = (sender as Button).ID;
    }
```

now how to access that dynamic text box which I created in addbutton method in side reply_Click , any idea ?

Comment: what is going on here? Please correct this so it is readable.

Comment: TextBox created there is local to that method.

Comment: than what could be the solution

Answer (score 0):

use this way :

```
this.FindControl("textbox Id")
```

note: use must add it to you page before use this command

Comment: how to aceess text box id that is also dynamic you can see in code what to write there

Comment: if you want to access to the textbox you need to have its ID

Comment: void addButtons(string buttonText) { if (ViewState["btnId"] == null) return; for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) { TextBox txt = new TextBox(); txt.Visible = false; txt.ID = "TXT" + i;} this will be the ID now how to use ion button event

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. getting this error when i am trying to access txtbox

Comment: string txtID = "TXT" + (sender as Button).ID;
        TextBox txtFirstName = this.FindControl(txtID) as TextBox;
        txtFirstName.Visible = true;

Comment: invalid textbox Id you pass to the FindControl method

Comment: than what could be the corrent id i think that text box scope is local only so any idea how to access that

Answer (score 0):

This sample creates 5 dynamic textboxes and buttons and finds a textbox when its corresponding button is clicked.

```
for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.ID = "txt" + i;
    this.Controls.Add( tb );

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.ID = "btn" + i;
    this.Controls.Add( btn );

    btn.CommandArgument = i.ToString();

    btn.Command += ( sender, e )
    {
        string id = "txt" + e.CommandArgument;
        TextBox textBox = this.FindControl( id ) as TextBox;
    };
}
```

Note that `FindControl` is not recursive, so be sure to call it on the immediate parent container of the control you are seeking.

I have used an anonymous delegate to handle the command event, but this could be placed outside of the control creation loop. It's important to note that all unique information must be passed to the event handler via the command arguments.

As a side note, ViewState is not required for any of this to work.

Comment: i have done same but getting error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when i am giving textBox.Visible= true;

Comment: @user1111351 - updated a syntax error in the code. If that does not work, please update your original post with the updated code.